# Error updating AppSetting with name is not allowed from Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

While updating an Azure App Service App Setting with Terraform we're getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"AppSetting with name 'HEALTHCHECKS-UI_HEALTHCHECKS_0_NAME' is not allowed."}
```

However if we add it via the portal manual it works totally fine:
[image]

I'm guessing it's something to do with the `0` or `-` but how do we escape these?

The Terraform code is pretty simple but here is a failing example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "test" {
  name                = "example-appserviceplan"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "test" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.test.id}"

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

  app_settings = {
    "HEALTHCHECKSUI_HEALTHCHECKS_0_NAME"  = "Self"
    "HEALTHCHECKSUI_HEALTHCHECKS_0_URI"   = "https://${var.environment_name}-example-app-service/health-api"
  }
}
```

Dropping into the bash terminal in kudo and running `printenv` shows that setting it manually removes the `-`:

```
HEALTHCHECKSUI_HEALTHCHECKS_0_NAME=https://example-app-service.azurewebsites.net/health-api
```

Comment: Could you include the terraform code that's around this issue and the full error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this error with linux_function_app and my problem seemed to be that I had dashes in my app_setting.
I changed them to Underscores and it worked.

I'm not aware that there was a restriction on using dashes in the app setting parameter names tho. I've used both dashes and underscores before.

Answer (score 1):

Remove **-** (Dash) from environment variables names. It will work fine

Ex: Test-Pass --> TestPass

Comment: I don't have control of the package using those environment variables naming convention with `-` so I can't remove it.

Comment: Change from application settings or ask the admin to do so

Comment: It's a 3rd party NuGet package, we want this as environment variables so it's configured like the test of the application

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I do not find the document to show the limitation of this for the app settings in Azure App Service. But as I know, the operating system has the limitation of this. For Linux, you cannot set the environment variable with the name contains `-`. But in Windows, the limitations for `-` does not exist. Generally, letters and numbers are no problem in both systems.

Comment: Thanks for the information, It's a bit annoying as HEALTHCHECKS-UI package requires a dash and it's impossible to pass it through.

Comment: @KevinSmith It's the environment variable limitation. But you can try another way, not the environment variable.

Comment: Totally understand it may be a limitation on some systems, but I find it odd that it works via the portal but not via Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error on the Azure portal while trying to connect cosmosDb with the Azure functions.
The root cause was that the Azure function app OS was configured as Linux and changing (creating a new app) to Windows resolved that error for me.